# Cannot set up New Oracle CDC service

Tags: oracle, ssms, change-data-capture

I am trying to get the Attunity CDC service to work for me on my laptop. I have created the MSXDBCDC database on my SQL Server and am in the process of setting up my first service

[image]

Test connection works fine.
I am using a service account that gets assigned to MSXDBCDC when I click OK on the above form
[image]

But then I get the following error

[image]

I am working from my laptop setting up a dev environment, but the SQL Server is on a server

Can you see anything glaringly obvious wrong with my approach?